# is there a way to remove all permissions from a folder using remote event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

Is there a way to programmatically to find if an item that has been added to a document library is a folder through a remote event receiver?

I want to remove all permissions when a folder is been added to the document library

Answer (score 1):

Check the `FileSystemObjectType` property of the added item to determine if it is folder.  To remove all permissions use `ListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This provides the answer to a part of the question where OP wants to check if item added is folder or not.

Comment: @waqas, I added the answer for second part as well. Do me a favour and ad the code part in my answer in code block.  I am on mobile so I don't have that option

Comment: I m on mobile as well :(

Comment: I've fixed it for you (I can write ` on my mobile)!

Comment: @robert, thanks.  You've got the better mobile :-)